# How to get all active threads and dump all stack symbols in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get all active thread and dump all active thread stack symbols.

I know PLCrashReporter was suitable, but it was heavy, I dont want to using it in my project. It was have another simple method to fix this question?

Comment: See the docs for `NSThread`.

Comment: NSThread just can get the current thread, but I want to get all active thread